# How to add an outlook calendar event to a shared calendar using Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, outlook-calendar

With this python code I can make an outlook event in my personal calendar but I would like to make an event in a shared outlook calendar.

FolderPath of the outlook calendar: \Public Folders - my.email@company.com\All Public Folders\COMPANY\Production
Can somebody please help me?

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#FolderPath of the outlook calendar: \\Public Folders - my.email@company.com\All Public Folders\COMPANY\Production

calendar_folder = ns.Session.Folders('Public Folders - my.email@company.com').Folders("All Public Folders").Folders("COMPANY").Folders("Production")

def Add_outlook_Event(when,subject):    
  appt = outlook.CreateItem(1) #<-- this works
  #appt = outlook.calendar_folder.CreateItem(1) <-- this does not work
  #appt = calendar_folder.CreateItem(1) <-- this does not work
  appt.Start = when # yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm
  appt.Subject = subject 
  appt.AllDayEvent = True
  appt.Save()
  appt.Send()

Add_outlook_Event("2023-03-10","New Outlook event for Bobby")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get a shared calendar folder. The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder). For example, the following VBA sample shows how to use the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Second, to add a new item to the shared folder you can use the `Add` method in the following way:

```
items = calendarFolder.Items;
appItem = items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
```

The `CreateItem` method can also be used for creating new items in Outlook. But in that case you need to move the created item to the target folder by using the `Move` method. Otherwise, it will be saved to the default folder. Read more about all possible ways of creating new Outlook items in the article which I wrote for the technical blog, see [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) for more information.